# Mixing external and embedded style in HTML head tag

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Title </title>
        <style>
            h1 {
                color: red;
            }
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
    </body>
```

The style.css contains the following:

```
h1 {
    color: green;
}
```

I was expecting the word 'TEST' color change to green because the order of statements in the head tag, but it is red. Please help, thank you.

Comment: You cannot use `<link>` elements inside `<style>`, it's just ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the

```
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet">
```

should be moved after your

```
</style>
```

tag

Comment: It worked as you (Birgit) said it, by removing the link tag from inside of style tag. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
  <style>
                h1 {
                    color: red;
                }            
            </style> <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```